# ajax and select element dropdown

Tags: html, ajax, jsp, select

**hello guys please i have an issue with ajax i have this function that fetch data from jsp but when i add a new data to the database and call the function again it duplicates the data unless i refresh the page which i don't want users to do**

```
       <script>
                                                                     
                                                                     search1();
                                                                          function search1(){
                                                                              $.ajax({
                                                                                  
                                                                                  type:"GET",
                                                                                  url:"drop.jsp",
                                                                                  dataType:'JSON',
                                                                                  data:{"title":'title'},
                                                                                  
                                                                                  success:function(data){
                                                                                      
                                                                                      console.log(data);
                                                                                      
                                                                                      for(var i = 0; i< data.length; i++){
                                                                                          $('#title').append($("<option/>",
                                                                                      {
                                                                                              
                                                                                             text: data[i].area, 
                                                                                              
                                                                                      }));  
                                                                                          
                                                                                      }
                                                                                     
                                                                                  },
                                                                                  error(err){
                                                                                      alert("error")
                                                                                  }
                                                                                  
                                                                                  
                                                                              });
                                                                              
                                                                          }
                                                                          
                                                                          
                                                                    </script>
```

**it fetch's data as i want but when i call that same function with another function it duplicate the dropdown data the second function is below**

```
    <script>
                                                                          function title2(){
                                                                              
                                                                        
                                                                              $.ajax({
                                                                                  
                                                                                  type:"POST",
                                                                                  url:"drop.jsp",
                                                                                  data:{"title1":$("#title1").val()},
                                                                                  
                                                                                  success:function(msg){
                                                                                      var obj = JSON.parse(msg);
                                                                                     
                                                                                      search1();
                                                                                  },
                                                                                  error(err){
                                                                                      alertify.error('Error');
                                                                                  }
                                                                                  
                                                                                  
                                                                              })
                                                                              
                                                                          }
                                                                          
                                                                          
                                                                    </script>
```

**and the jsp code is**

```
String title = request.getParameter("title");
        String marital = request.getParameter("marital");
        String minis = request.getParameter("minis");
        String occu = request.getParameter("occu");
        String job = request.getParameter("job");
        String bs = request.getParameter("bs");
        String class1 = request.getParameter("class1");
        String course = request.getParameter("course");
        JSONArray list =new JSONArray();
        
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/cop","root","root");
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        
        if(title != null){
        String sql = "Select * from title";
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
        while(rs.next()){
            
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            String area = rs.getString("title");
            
            obj.put("area", area);
            list.add(obj);
            
        }
        out.println(list.toJSONString());
        out.flush();
        }
```

**and the output is in the image**
[the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hj089.png)

Comment: you probably have to remove all previous option elements in the select before adding new ones?

Comment: how do i do that

Comment: since you are using jquery, before appending more `option` elements, use `.empty()` to remove all previous `option` elements in it

Comment: can i get a snippet please